# How to easily plot a 3D array as a surface in C++?

Tags: c++, plot

I would like to plot a 3D array and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I know I could download gnuplot and spend time creating my function but I am sure many of you already did so.

So I am wondering where I can find the code for a function that will take as an input 3 vectors (`std::vector<double>`) and generate a surface plot.

Comment: I recommend searching [softwarerecs.se] for "c++ plot library".

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard c++ plotting library. You have to look at some 3-thd party library to do this. For ex. check vtk, gnuplot.